# Keeping LED constantly on with BeagleBone black and python

Tags: python, gpio, beagleboneblack, adafruit

I have a small circuit plugged into a Beaglebone Black,

What I would like is to keep a white LED constantly on.

If I run the following code the LED turns on briefly ad then turns off again.

```
import Adafruit_BBIO.GPIO as GPIO
import time

GPIO.setup("P8_14", GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.output("P8_14", GPIO.HIGH)
```

I have tried the following:

```
import Adafruit_BBIO.GPIO as GPIO
import time

GPIO.setup("P8_14", GPIO.OUT)
while True:
    GPIO.output("P8_14", GPIO.HIGH)
```

Which will keep it constantly on but I have a feeling its actually blinking to fast for me to see. And if for example I have a bunch of code in the while loop then it blinks again (assuming the `time.sleep(1)` represents code that takes a second to run):

```
GPIO.setup("P8_14", GPIO.OUT)
while True:
    GPIO.output("P8_14", GPIO.HIGH)
    time.sleep(1)
```

Is there anyway to say to a pin to be on constantly with Python ?

Thanks for your help,

Answer (score 0):

P8_14 -- this is digital Input/Output pin.
To setup a digital pin as an output, set the output value to HIGH, and then cleanup after you're done:

```
GPIO.setup("P8_10", GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.output("P8_10", GPIO.HIGH)
GPIO.cleanup()
```

For blink leds or turn it on use USR0, USR1, USR2 and USR3.

For blinking onboard leds try this example:

```
for i in range(4):
    GPIO.setup("USR%d" % i, GPIO.OUT)

while True:
    for i in range(4): # Turn Leds ON
        GPIO.output("USR%d" % i, GPIO.HIGH)
        time.sleep(1)
    for i in range(4): # Turn Leds Off
        GPIO.output("USR%d" % i, GPIO.LOW)
        time.sleep(1)
```

Comment: Thanks for the additional info but my question remains, if I run 'GPIO.output("P8_14", GPIO.HIGH)' it only turns on for a brief moment. Is there any way to keep it on constantly ? In my last example it blinks when I don't want it to.

Comment: GPIO.setup("USR0", GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.output("USR0", GPIO.HIGH)
Dont work?

Comment: Yes that works with the LED on the actual BeagleBone. Sorry I was not clear in my question. I have a personal LED I am trying to light up and it is plugged into the digital ouput 'P8_14' and that is the one I can't seem to keep 'high'

Comment: P8_14 is digital output, not analog. You must connect to that pin some trigger logic if u want to do that. Triac diode for example - the simplest.